# MapStruct: exclude property based on (boolean) value

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm aware that MapStruct can ignore unmapped properties and specific target properties, but is it possible to exlcude a property based on its actual value?

I have boolean fields which I would like to exclude only if they are false.

Thanks in advance!

Example:

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle")
@Getter @Setter
public class Vehicle {
   @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private boolean hasWheels;
   private boolean hasWings;
   private boolean hasBrakes;
}
```

DTO:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class VehicleDTO {

   private String name;
   private boolean hasWheels;
   private boolean hasWings;
   private boolean hasBrakes;
}
```

MapStruct Mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface VehicleMapper {

// Entity to DTO:
VehicleDTO toVehicleDTO(Vehicle vehicle);
List<VehicleDTO> toVehicleDTOs(List<Vehicle> vehicles);

// DTO to Entity:
Vehicle toVehicle(VehicleDTO vehicleDTO);
}
```

I would like to fully exclude the boolean variables only if their value is "false".

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: I added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapStruct has the concept of [Source presence checking](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#source-presence-check). By default (when an implicit conversion is happening) it checks if the source value is `null` before assigning it to the target. There also a way of [Checking source property for `null` arguments](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#checking-source-property-for-null-arguments) by using the the option `nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS`, which will always include a `null` check when source is non primitive, unless a source presence checker is defined on the source bean.

Having said all this. Since in your case the source properties are primitive boolean, you can achieve this by adding a presence check for those fields. Thus eliminating the need for an expression.

e.g. for the DTO

```
@Getter @Setter
public class VehicleDTO {

    private String name;
    private boolean hasWheels;
    private boolean hasWings;
    private boolean hasBrakes;

    public boolean hasHasWheels() {
        return hasWheels;
    }
}
```

With this the implementation would first check if the DTO has `hasWheels` and only then set it to the target.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a clean way to do in MapStruct. One way is to use expressions in mapstruct. I guess the below code might help.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface VehicleMapper {

@Mapping(target = "hasWheels", expression = "java((hasWheels)?hasWheels:false)")
Vehicle toVehicle(VehicleDTO vehicleDTO);
}
```

However you have used primitive type boolean variables which has 'false' default value though u set or ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson to ignore the null fields.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class VehicleDTO
```

In the below method don't just set the Boolean fields in DTO if the value is false.

// Entity to DTO:

VehicleDTO toVehicleDTO(Vehicle vehicle);

You can also Spring BeanUtils to copy and override copyProperties method.

```
public static String[] gePropertyNames(Object source) {
    final BeanWrapper wrappedSource = new BeanWrapperImpl(source);
    return Stream.of(wrappedSource.getPropertyDescriptors())
            .map(FeatureDescriptor::getName)
            .filter(propertyName -> {
                    if(wrappedSource.getPropertyValue(propertyName) != null && wrappedSource.getPropertyValue(propertyName) instanceof Boolean){
                        Boolean value = (Boolean) wrappedSource.getPropertyValue(propertyName);
                        if(value){
                            return false;
                        }else{
                            return true;
                        }
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
            }).toArray(String[]::new);
}

// then use Spring BeanUtils to copy and ignore properties using our function
public static void myCopyProperties(Object src, Object target) {
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(src, target, gePropertyNames(src));
}
```